# How can I use Kong’s Capturing Group in Ingress k8s object for rewirting logic?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kong, kong-plugin, kong-ingress

I want to use Kong’s Capturing Group in Ingress k8s object to perform an uri rewriting.
I want to implement the following logic:
https://kong_host:30000/service/audits/health -> (rewrite) https://kong_host:30000/service/audit/v1/health

Ingress resource:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: audits
  annotations:
    konghq.com/plugins: audits-rewrite
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /service/audits/(?<path>\\\S+)
        backend:
          serviceName: audits
          servicePort: 8080
```

KongPlugin

```
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
  name: audits-rewrite
config: 
  replace:
    uri: /service/audit/v1/$(uri_captures["path"])
plugin: request-transformer
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed in documentation you are not able to use `v1beat1` ingress API version to capture groups in paths.

https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/request-transformer/#examples

You need to upgrade you `k8s` cluster to `1.19` or higher version to use this feature.

I also had similar problem and resolved it will following configuration:

Ingress resource:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: audits
  annotations:
    konghq.com/plugins: audits-rewrite
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /service/audits/(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: audits
          servicePort: 8080
```

KongPlugin

```
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
  name: audits-rewrite
config: 
  replace:
    uri: /service/audit/v1/$(uri_captures[1])
plugin: request-transformer
```